# keep Classes fixed after other classes shown/hidden

Tags: css

I need images to stay fixed just where they're placed at start,and search and login forms to be shown exactly under the corresponding image (lens for search and man for login).I'd like to keep .classes and not create any #id,because classes are in a #id yet in my complete site.Full code in jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/6ara3d1m/3/

```
.login-carrello {
margin-right: 0;
margin-top: 3.5%;
color: #BC9B1B;
float: right;
 }
.search_form{
 vertical-align:top;
display: none;
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is make sure to **clear** the two elements you are floating to the right (`.login` and `.search_form`):

```
.login, .search_form {
  clear: both;
}
```

You'll also want to slightly change the structure so that the `.login-carello` comes first:

```
<div class="login-carrello"></div>
<div class="login"></div>
<div class="search_form"></div>
```

```js
function showhide() {
  var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName('search_form')[0];
  var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName('login')[0];
  if (div2.style.display == "block") {
    div2.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    div2.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (div1.style.display == "block") {
    div1.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    div1.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function showhide2() {
  var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName('search_form')[0];
  var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName('login')[0];
  if (div1.style.display == "block") {
    div1.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    div1.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (div2.style.display == "block") {
    div2.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    div2.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.login-carrello {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 3.5%;
  color: #BC9B1B;
  float: right;
}

.search_form {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: none;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

.login {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 7%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-carrello">
  <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/2uz2omc.png" onClick="showhide();" width="50px" height="50px">
  <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/qrhda0.jpg" onClick="showhide2();" width="50px" height="50px">
</div>

<div class="login">
  <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="" method="post">
    <p class="login-username">
      <label for="user_login">Nome utente</label>
      <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" />
    </p>
    <p class="login-password">
      <label for="user_pass">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" />
    </p>

    <p class="login-remember">
      <label>
        <input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" checked="checked" /> Ricordami</label>
    </p>
    <p class="login-submit">
      <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary" value="Login &rarr;" />
      <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="search_form">
  <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
  <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Cerca" />
</div>
```

I've created a new fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/4xuej6c3/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks,your way is  good,  .login and .search-form now appear in the position i wanted,but imgs in .login-carrello still move to left when clicked,so when  .login or .search-form get shown,lefting an ugly black space.I need to keep them aligned to the right side.Some screenshots   http://i67.tinypic.com/10fchmc.png http://i67.tinypic.com/3516b7q.png http://i66.tinypic.com/30toww5.png